# Points will create rectangle or not if yes then calculate area

Tags: c#, point, rectangles

I have array of 4 points and I want to check whether these points will create a rectangle or not. If it will create a rectangle than calculate area of this.
x,y value of point can be positive or negative or mix of it.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far. You can't just post something like this and expect someone to give you a full implementation.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the **six** distances between the **four** points.

Use [Pythagoras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) for this.

If they result in **three** pairs of **equal non-zero** distances it is a rectangle.

The **product** of the **shorter two** is its **area**.

Make sure not to fall into rounding error traps; so use an epsilon criterion  when comparing for 'equality' as floating point numbers have a tendency to not be equal even if they should be mathematically!